# Echo based on number of items selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, switch-statement, case

```
<form action="exercise2.php" method="post"> 
    Type your name: <input type="text" name="name2" ><br>

    Toyota<input name="vehicle[]" type="checkbox" value="Toyota"><br>
    Bmw<input name="vehicle[]" type="checkbox" value="Bmw"><br>
    Audi<input name="vehicle[]" type="checkbox" value="Audi"><br>
    Subaru<input name="vehicle[]" type="checkbox" value="Subaru"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

** So the thing is; when I don't choose any vehicle, program crashes, when it's supposed to get in case 1.
**

I want to echo vehicles, e.g. when two or three options are checked.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name2'];
$vehicles = $_POST['vehicle'];
$cont=0;

foreach($vehicles as $i){
    $cont++;
}

switch($cont){
    case 0:
        echo "You should choose some favs";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "$name, you should look for more fav cars";
        break;

    case 4:
        echo "$name, I think you have too many fav cars";
        break;
}?>
```

Comment: You should output the contents of your `$_POST` variable (e.g. with `var_dump`) to understand what's in there when you don't check anything.

Comment: $vehicles = $_POST['vehicle']; should be $vehicles = !empty($_POST['vehicle']) ? $_POST['vehicle']:[0];

Comment: When there's nothing selected in checkbox, program crashes. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over an array that doesn't exist. The form sends nothing on checkboxes when not checked, so you need to change your php:

```
<?php
# If you are echoing this back, it's good to sanitize it a bit
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name2']);
# Make the default be an empty array
$vehicles = (!empty($_POST['vehicle']))? $_POST['vehicle'] : [];
$cont=0;
# This won't fail because it can iterate an empty array
foreach($vehicles as $i){
    $cont++;
}
# 0 should now work
switch($cont){
    case 0:
        echo "You should choose some favs";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "$name, you should look for more fav cars";
        break;

    case 4:
        echo "$name, I think you have too many fav cars";
        break;
}
```

Also turn on errors, it would have told you it can't iterate over `empty`.